# Vanilla equivalent to wrapInner() for placing tags inside li (unordered lists)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, html-lists, tailwind-css, wrapinner

Is there any way to do the jquery wrapInner() to add items inside an unordered list but with Vanilla javascript, if I could use jquery I would use something like `$('li').wrapInner('<div class="bg-white shadow-lg"></div>');` but I can not use jquery, and have not been successful trying to make a function to work like this.

I have a dynamic list that is for example

```
<ul>
  <li>Text from teh database</li>
  <li>Dynamic text</li>
  <li>A text</li>
</ul>
```

I need to add div inside of them with a class in there

```
<ul>
  <li><div class="bg-white shadow-lg">Text from teh database</div></li>
  <li><div class="bg-white shadow-lg">Dynamic text</div></li>
  <li><div class="bg-white shadow-lg">A text</div></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way I can add those divs with class with vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this isn't difficult at all. First, you get all the elements with `querySelectorAll` (you probably want a better starting element than `document`). Then, for each element in that list, you create a `div` and give it the appropriate `className` property.

Then you loop through the `childNodes` of the original list item and add them to the wrapping element (this removes them from their original location). Finally, with the original list item empty, you add the wrapping element to it.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (let item of items) {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.className = 'bg-white shadow-lg';

  for (let itemContent of item.childNodes) {
    wrapper.appendChild(itemContent);
  }

  item.appendChild(wrapper);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Text from teh database</li>
  <li>Dynamic text</li>
  <li>A text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That is great, what should I use if the text has HTML like an <h2> tags and <p> tags?

Comment: @Somelight You'll need to find other ways of traversing the DOM and adapt this code to match. It sounds fairly simple, though.